# Catching errors being thrown within module

Tags: python, error-handling, gevent

I'm using gevent's WSGIServer's `serve_forever()` method with my own certificate.
Something like this:

```
http_server = WSGIServer(arguments)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Obviously, since the certificate isn't recognised, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 34, in _handle_and_close_when_done
    return handle(*args_tuple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/server.py", line 233, in wrap_socket_and_handle
    with _closing_socket(self.wrap_socket(client_socket, **self.ssl_args)) as ssl_socket:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 802, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 312, in __init__
    raise x
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 308, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 667, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:1091)
2021-02-25T07:44:54Z <Greenlet at 0x7f5d8ffe5b90: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method StreamServer.wrap_socket_and_handle , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed] at 0x7f5d9b91a1d)> failed with SSLError
```

I tried to pass a file object to the `error_log` argument:

```
file_with_errors = open("path/to/file", "+w")
http_server = WSGIServer(arguments, error_log=file_with_errors)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

and I tried simply catching the error:

```
http_server = WSGIServer(arguments)
try:
    http_server.serve_forever()
except:
    do_something()
```

but none of these work, which tells me that the error is being thrown and logged somewhere within the gevent module.

To confirm this, I tried:

```
import io

def func():
    http_server = WSGIServer(arguments)
    http_server.serve_forever()

try:
    _orig_stderr = sys.stderr
    _new_stderr = io.StringIO()
    sys.stderr = _new_stderr
    func()
except:
    file_with_errors = open("path/to/file", "+w")
    _new_stderr.seek(0)
    output = _new_stderr.read()
    file_with_errors.write(output)
    sys.stderr = _orig_stderr
    file_with_errors.close()
```

and sent a KeyboardInterrupt, which worked. The errors were logged in the file.

Is there any way for me to catch and redirect the error traceback?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import logging
import traceback
from wsgiref.simple_server import WSGIServer

logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()

try:
    http_server = WSGIServer(arguments)
    http_server.serve_forever()
except:
    logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, it prints anything coming through via the gevent console to a text file.

```
import logging, sys
from logging import handlers

level = logging.getLevelName('INFO')
log = logging.getLogger('')
log.setLevel(level)
format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logs/streamlog.txt', maxBytes=(1048576 * 5), backupCount=3)
fh.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(fh)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import logging, sys
from logging import handlers

level = logging.getLevelName('INFO')
log = logging.getLogger('')
log.setLevel(level)
format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
fh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logs/streamlog.txt', maxBytes=(1048576 * 5), backupCount=3)
fh.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(fh)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the gevent uwsgi documentation error_log is  a file-like object with write, writelines and flush methods to which error logs will be written not a filename

> log – If given, an object with a write method to which request
> (access) logs will be written. If not given, defaults to sys.stderr.
> You may pass None to disable request logging. You may use a wrapper,
> around e.g., logging, to support objects that don’t implement a write
> method. (If you pass a Logger instance, or in general something that
> provides a log method but not a write method, such a wrapper will
> automatically be created and it will be logged to at the INFO level.)
>
> error_log – If given, a file-like object with write, writelines and
> flush methods to which error logs will be written. If not given,
> defaults to sys.stderr. You may pass None to disable error logging
> (not recommended). You may use a wrapper, around e.g., logging, to
> support objects that don’t implement the proper methods. This
> parameter will become the value for wsgi.errors in the WSGI
> environment (if not already set). (As with log, wrappers for Logger
> instances and the like will be created automatically and logged to at
> the ERROR level.)

you can try this :

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("path/to/file.log")
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
http_server = WSGIServer(arguments, error_log=logger)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

**Another Solution**

Gevent writes all the logs to stderr, you can redirect everything that is written to stderr to your log file and since sys.stderr is nothing but a file object, you cannot be sure if Gevent is not using other methods on sys.stderr elsewhere in the code. so you have to override only sys.stderr.write leave everything intact so that any other use of sys.stderr does not break Gevent, and your application.

```
class RedirectStderr(file):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._cfg = kwargs.pop('cfg')
        self._log_file = open(self._cfg['access_log_path'], 'a')
        super(RedirectStderr, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def write(self, msg):
        # Just in-case you want to write to both stderr and another log file
        super(RedirectStderr, self).write(msg)

        # Write to another access log file
        self._log_file.write(msg)
        self._log_file.flush()

        # Or use Python's logging facility to log the standard way you log
        # across your project
        log.info(msg)

    def close(self):
        super(RedirectStderr, self).close()
        self._log_file.close()

import sys
sys.stderr = RedirectStderr('path/to/file', 'w', cfg=cfg)
```

you can read more about in this [link](https://medium.com/vaidikkapoor/problems-with-logging-while-using-gevents-wsgi-server-3d19fbca3de1)